# config.xmlに記載されているバックエンドのIDやApiKey

Tags: monaca

config.xmlにバックエンドのIDやApiKeyが記載されてますが、悪用される心配は無いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

具体的にどういう風に悪用されるストーリーを考えているのかを書いて質問してみてください。
そうすれば、そのストーリーの実現可否を答えてもらえると思います。

悪用される心配があるのか？ないのか？だけで聞かれればなんでもかんでも『悪用される可能性はあります！』としか答えようがありません。

Comment: アプリを複製し第三者が同一バックエンドを利用する事ができるのではないかと思いました。